# Sails.js security issue on beforeCreate, sails is adding relations to others models even if I deleted that parameters

Tags: javascript, sails.js

first this is my **beforeCreate** function:

```
  beforeCreate: function (values, next) {
    console.log("before, "+values.followers);
    if (values.followers) {
      values.followers = undefined; //or null
      console.log("after, "+values.followers);
    };
  }
```

My model has:

```
followers: {
  collection: 'user',
  via: 'followingTopics'
},
```

And the output in console is:

**before, "the user id that was send as a parameter"**

**after, undefined (or null)**

But the relation is created.

I need that a bad user can't auto make followers for him.
How can I prevent this? Only working with polices or direct on the controller?

Thank you

Comment: Ok, this solve the problem:


`if (values.followers) {

        return next({ err: 'Error, no puedes suscribir usuarios a tu tema' });

      };`

but it's interesting that I can't change that value on the **beforeCreate** function, if you have a comment or feedback please let me know

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try `delete values.followers`?

Comment: Thank you! this help me to see how to solve the problem. I'll put the answer here in a while

Comment: sorry, I thought I had found the answer because I noticed that when I call the create function with blueprints, and send followers as a parameter, not only the beforeCreate method is calling but also the before and after Update too. And that sounds logic. So I thought that I can delete valuesToUpdate.followers or set it to undefined, but It doesn't work, followers is not defined unless the parameter comes from the update blueprint route. So that is so weird.

Only to provide more details if I try delete values.followers, still it has not effect.